# How to make sure, that my add to the list keeps, even after switch from apps

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios, mobile-devices

I do have a website, where I can add some notes to a list. Usually I do it with `copy & paste` function

On each click of `Add to the list` button on my Website, Javascript generats HTML. So the new entry appends to the existing list.

**Issue:**

When I visit my Website with my mobile device, the 'Add to the list' button works fine.

But the issue is, if I go out from the mobile browser, to copy some new notes, and switch back to the mobile browser, the list is empty.

**Question:**

How can I keep the add to the list content - even I switch the browser on my mobile device?

**Please note**, these elements of the list, are only temporary. They are only for preparing purpose, so no need to store them specially in a database or whatever. They shouldn't use any storage on webserver or whatever.

---

**My JS: *(just for imagine, how I generate my HTML)***

```
function js_buildHTML(input_text) {
var html = '';

html += 'some' + input_Text + 'content';
html += 'some content';

$('#id_myList').after(html);
}
```

Comment: Look into [web storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API) or store on a server

Comment: @mplungjan Thank you, I will check that. But please note, this elements of the list, are only temporary. They are only for preparing, so no need to store them specially on a database or whatever. They shouldn't use any storage on webserver or whatever.

Comment: So web storage is the new cookies